# LEFT JOIN MYSQL full text search - search multiple columns cross table

Tags: mysql, search

I have two tables:

Table 1: Content   [title, description, url, genre_id]
Table 2: Genre [genre_id, genre_name]

I'm trying to run a FULL SEARCH query so that if someone searches for a genre, the details from the Content will be returned. Equally if someone searches for a title, the Content will be returned as normal. Note that some Contents do not have a genre assigned so it will need to work in this scenario.

This is my query - I just can't work out how to get it working...

```
"SELECT content.*, genre.* FROM content LEFT OUTER JOIN genre 
ON (genre.genre_id=content.genre_id) 
WHERE MATCH (content.title, content.description) 
AGAINST ('$query') 
OR MATCH (genre.genre_name) 
AGAINST ('$query') 
AND content.url IS NOT NULL AND content.url <> '' LIMIT $lowerlimit, 10";
```

Comment: Your title says LEFT join but your code shows INNER join, maybe that's it?

Comment: my apologies- I did have it set as LEFT join but have been trying numerous options!

Answer (score 0):

If you have Content items that don't have genre_id's, then INNER JOIN is not the way to go. That will exclude any Content items that don't have genre-id's. Use a LEFT OUTER JOIN instead. This assumes that there are no Genres whose genre_id's don't have a corresponding Content item. If the latter is the case, you need to create some kind of dummy row in your Content table to handle this. If this doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll give you more detail.

Comment: Hi Melanie - i've now used LEFT OUTER JOIN but you're right that I might have some genre_ids that have no content (I can force this to not be the case though...) Unfortunately the query is still showing errors

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiarized with the `WHERE MATCH ** AGAINST **`, but I believe it could be rewritten to:

```
SELECT content.*, genre.*
FROM content
LEFT OUTER JOIN genre 
    ON genre.genre_id = content.genre_id
WHERE (content.title LIKE '%' + '$query' + '%'
    OR content.description LIKE '%' + '$query' + '%'
    OR genre.genre_name LIKE '%' + '$query' + '%')
AND content.url IS NOT NULL
AND content.url <> ''
LIMIT $lowerlimit, 10;
```

I also noted in your query there's a additional double quote at the end, before the semicolon.

Comment: hmm this works if I don't use the + symbols between the wild card and query - was trying to avoid LIKE though as I heard it has performance issues